# Unity3D WebCamTexture graphicsFormat value doesn't exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, texture2d

I wanted to check which UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.GraphicsFormat my WebCamTexture is using.

```
WebCamTexture webCam = new WebCamTexture();
Debug.Log($"Graphics Format is {webCam.graphicsFormat}");
```

The output is `Graphics Format is 88` but 88 does not seem to be in the GraphicsFormat enum, which goes up to 86 and then continues at 96.

So which format is the WebCamTexture using?

EDIT: I am using Unity 2019.4.21f1 for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

88 is `ARGB32`, even though it's not part of the named enum values.

Edit: the full list of undocumented options is as follows:

- Alpha8 54
- ARGB32 88
- YUY2 141
- ASTC_HDR_4x4 145
- ASTC_HDR_5x5 146
- ASTC_HDR_6x6 147
- ASTC_HDR_8x8 148
- ASTC_HDR_10x10 149
- ASTC_HDR_12x12 150
- PVRTC_2BPP_RGBA 108875872